# Android Virtual Device (AVD) -- which CPU/ABI should I select?

Tags: android, android-emulator

When creating an AVD, there are three options to select for CPU/ABI:

- ARM
- Mips
- Intel Atom

What are the differences and which should I choose?  Is there one that covers most devices?

Comment: Intel Atom should provide you with good performance though I have used ARM intitially. It should depend mostly on your pc specs

Comment: ARM covers the most devices currently. It won't hurt to test against them all, though.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to the android developer documentation you should actually create a virtual device for every framework and platform you intend to run the code on, that being said the majority of mobile devices in the market currently run on the ARM architecture.. you should still test your code on a distinct virtual appliance for each level of the framework that your code supports though.

> **System Image**
>   Recommended. Although you might have one or more Android-powered devices on which to test your app, it's unlikely you have a device for every version of Android your app supports. It's a good practice to download system images for all versions of Android your app supports and test your app running on them with the Android emulator.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

Comment: Thx for the answer.  I've searched for, but have not found, data to support the majority of devices run on the ARM architecture. I'd love to see some data or charts that show which device has which CPU/ABI.

Comment: @TrippinBilly You are correct in that it is difficult to find hard evidence of this, the evidence that exists publicly is anecdotal at best. If you want concrete data I think your best bet is to write to the chip manufacturers to see if you can get a count clients that have purchased Android-ready products.

Answer (score 13):

90% of the mobile devices are powered by ARM. So it will be a better option

Answer (score 4):

You should choose ARM since it's old processor that almost mobiles use.

Answer (score 2):

The Atom Emulation is way faster, so i would use these for developing and final test on arm-mode or with a real phone.

Answer (score 1):

> There are three main CPU architectures used in today's Android phones. ARM is perhaps the most common, as it's optimized for battery consumption. ARM64 is an evolution of the original ARM architecture that supports 64-bit processing for more powerful computing, and it's quickly becoming the standard in newer devices.

From: https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/android-basics-see-what-kind-processor-you-have-arm-arm64-x86-0168051/